# How to configure next.config.js file on right way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my `next.config.js` I have the following configuration:

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withImages = require('next-images');
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');

module.exports = withCSS(
  withSass(
    withFonts(),  // <=== this is wrong? 
    withImages({
      distDir: '../_next',
      webpack(config) {
        return config;
      }
    })
  )
);
```

Last thing which I need to add here is **next-fonts** plugin.

I am not sure how to export `withFounts` in the right way.

I need next-fonts plugin to be able to use `'fonts' icons`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
module.exports = withCSS(withFonts(withSass(
    withImages({
        distDir: '../_next',
        webpack(config) {
            return config;
        }
    })
)))
```

You can try to use [next-compose](https://github.com/JerryCauser/next-compose)